# Calculating MS Word Equation value

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I was wondering whether or not a built-in method exists for calculating values input in Equation Tools in MS Word.

[image]

This is the value I'd like to calculate. I tried adding "Calculate" to the Quick Access Toolbar but to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the [Equation Editor](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702) is used to write/ edit an equation or a formula.

If you want to calculate the result, please use [Formula function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27) in a table.

[image]

Or you may use the Field code to calculate. More information, please refer to "[How to calculate formulas in a Word document](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/how_to_calculate_formulas_in_a_word_document.html)".

Comment: Thank you Emily for your response. Can this answer be interpreted as a thoughtful way of saying "no, there isn't" ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Okay, I've accepted your answer then.